# In showing what gain and phase lag are in an nth-order, linear differential equation with constant coefficients, why do we introduce a modulus term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying linear differential equations with constant coefficients. I saw the following derivation to show what gain and phase lag are ([original source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-ii-second-order-constant-coefficient-linear-equations/gain-and-phase-lag/MIT18_03SCF11_s15_1text.pdf)):

nth-order linear constant coefficient DE, inhomogeneous
$$a_n x^{(n)}+a_{n-1}x^{(n-1)}+...+a_1 x' +a_0x=q(t)$$

we can represent this using a linear operator p
$$p(D)x=q(t)$$

consider the case where we have sinusoidal input
$$p(D)x=B\cos(\omega t)$$

use complex replacement
$$p(D)z=Be^{i\omega t}$$

we know a particular solution using the exponential response formula
$$z_p=\frac{B}{p(i\omega)}e^{i\omega t}$$

**My issue is in the following step.**

To obtain a particular solution of the original equation in x
$$x_p=Re(z_p)=\frac{B}{|p(i\omega)|}\cos(\omega t - \phi), \phi=Arg(p(i \omega))$$

Here we can see that $x_p$, the output signal, is the input signal $cos(\omega t)$ but with a gain of $\frac{1}{|p(i\omega)|}$ and phase lag $\phi$.

But how do we justify introducing the modulus of $p(i\omega)$ in this derivation?, ie $|p(i\omega)|$?